# To discriminate the periodically repeating digits of the expansion of a non-negative rational number in a positive integer base

Tags: python, algorithm, number-theory

I implemented an algorithm which, for a given non-negative rational number `r` and a positive interger `b`, computes all of the digits of the expansion of `r` in base `b`. The algorithm itself actually outputs a function `f(i: int)` satisfying the equation `n = ... + f(-2)*b**-2 + f(-1)*b**-1 + f(0)*b**0 + f(1)*b**1 + f(2)*b**2 + ...`, and it computes the digits of the whole and fractional parts of `r` separately through two other auxiliary functions.

Below is my code in Python (3.10.2). It looks weird for Python code because I'm actually implementing the algorithm in MIT/GNU Scheme (15.3) and "sketching" it on Python. I'm showing the Python implementation instead of the Scheme one mostly because I believe it's easier to formulate this question (and actually have it answered) in Python.

```py
# `base`: convert a non-negative fraction to any positive integer base

from fractions import Fraction

# a natural number is a integer greater than or equal to 0
def is_natural(n):
    return isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0

# a fractional is a positive rational number strictly between 0 and 1
def is_fractional(x):
    return isinstance(x, Fraction) and 0 < x < 1

# given a natural number `n` and a positive integer `b` as, compute the base
# `b` expansion of `n` as a unary procedure `f` over the integers such that
#   n = ... + f(-2)b^-2 + f(-1)b^-1 + f(0)b^0 + f(1)b^1 + f(2)b^2 + ...
#
# since `n` is a  natural number, then f(i) = 0 for any integer `i` such that
# either i < 0 or i > log_b n. thus, there are only finitely many non-trivial
# values of `f` to compute
def natural_to_proc(n, b):
    if not is_natural(n):
        raise SyntaxError("%s is not a natural number." % n)
    if not (isinstance(b, int) and b > 0):
        raise SyntaxError("%s is not a positive integer." % b)

    def proc(i: int):
        if i < 0:
            return 0

        j = -1
        q = n
        while j != i:
            j += 1
            r = q % b
            q = q // b

        return r

    return proc

# given a fractional number `x` and a positive integer `b` as, compute the base
# `b` expansion of `n` as a unary procedure `f` over the integers such that
#   n = ... + f(-2)b^-2 + f(-1)b^-1 + f(0)b^0 + f(1)b^1 + f(2)b^2 + ...
#
# since `x` is a fractional number, then f(i) = 0 for any integer i >= 1 and,
# for some integer j < 0, f(i) is periodic for all integers i < j. thus, there
# are only finitely many non-trivial values of `f` to compute
def fractional_to_proc(x, b):
    if not is_fractional(x):
        raise SyntaxError("%s is not a fractional number." % x)
    if not (isinstance(b, int) and b > 0):
        raise SyntaxError("%s is not a positive integer." % b)

    n = x.numerator
    d = x.denominator

    def proc(i: int):
        if i > 0:
            return 0
        
        j = 1
        r = n
        while j != i:
            j -= 1
            q = r // d
            r = (r % d) * b

        return q

    return proc

# given a non-negative rational number `r` and a positive integer `b` as,
# compute the base `b` expansion of `n` as a unary procedure `f` over the
# integers such that
#   n = ... + f(-2)b^-2 + f(-1)b^-1 + f(0)b^0 + f(1)b^1 + f(2)b^2 + ...
#
# since `r` is a rational number, then there are a natural number `n` and a
# fractional number `x` such that r = n + x. thus, the expansion of `r` is
# simply the concatenation of the expansions of `n` and `x`
def rational_to_proc(r, b):
    if not (isinstance(r, Fraction) and r >= 0):
        raise SyntaxError("%s is not a non-negative fraction." % r)
    if not (isinstance(b, int) and b > 0):
        raise SyntaxError("%s is not a positive integer." % b)

    n = r.numerator // r.denominator
    x = r - n

    def proc(i: int):
        if i < 0:
            return fractional_to_proc(x, b)(i)
        return natural_to_proc(n, b)(i)

    return proc
```

Now, I want to implement an auxiliary algorithm which, given such a function `f(i)`, computes which digits are periodically repeating and discriminate them from the remaining digits. More especifically, I want it to output a list `l` such that `l[0]` is a (possibly empty) list of the digits of the whole part of `r`, `l[1:-1]` is a list of the non-periodically repeating digits of the fractional part of `r` if there are any (otherwise `l[1:-1]` is empty), and `l[-1]` is a list of the periodically repeating digits of the fractional part of `r` (if there are any, otherwise `l[-1] = []`), where `l[0]` is ordered from the least to most significant digit and the other two lists are ordered from the most to the least significant digit. For instance, the output for 2376661/33000 in base 10 should be `[[2, 7], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3]]` since its decimal expansion is 72.020[03].

My question is: how would I go about implementing this second algorithm? More especifically, how would I discriminate the periodically repeating digits from the others, provided I know ahead of time that the input is a non-negative rational number?

Comment: @Pychopath, I had 2376661/33000 in my clipboaard instead of 89167/3300, which is the correct fraction having that decimal expansion. I'll edit the post with the correct decimal expansion of this other fraction.

Comment: @Pychopath, that was another typo. It's corrected now. I hope I didn't mess up anything else.

Comment: Looks good now, and it's btw a very nice and well-written question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. Split into whole and fractional part
2. Extract the whole digits by repeatedly dividing by `b` until there's nothing left.
3. Extract the fractional digits by repeatedly multiplying with `b` until we reach a fraction we've seen before.
4. Split the fractional digits at the place where we first saw the final fractional value.

```
def analyze(r, b):
    whole, fractional = divmod(r, 1)

    whole_digits = []
    while whole:
        whole, digit = divmod(whole, b)
        whole_digits.append(digit)

    fractional_digits = []
    seen = {}
    while fractional not in seen:
        seen[fractional] = len(fractional_digits)
        digit, fractional = divmod(fractional * b, 1)
        fractional_digits.append(digit)

    s = seen[fractional]
    return [whole_digits,
            fractional_digits[:s],
            fractional_digits[s:] if fractional else []]
```

Demo usage:

```
from fractions import Fraction

r = Fraction(2376661, 33000)
b = 10

print(float(r))
print(analyze(r, b))
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLRasQgEHz3K/ZRSyhJA2kJ3Gt/IoSSNNoTjIralmvpt6fG806vCdS32ZmdnV3UJ3dUsn7SZlkmymCQgzh9UWwKGEmLwL/PoxK0AGaGV8eV5@EAE/@Y1bSqKoKS6mXib9xZL@j6WOWCnrmzWWYYtMkrVkdyq4uW94PWVE44oDgyJdrMtZRKj75/shTZAlI54DKoUqwVdUnU@35BJd5MSQED3r9MVruDMZzp0rUx3Ntt3eVvoEAY6t6NhC4/TnH13vXvWtv/J7FtD5zlq1BhqT9njxAzar4yFvislXHwHAsIGZ/1gvBD/dg0TVVAXZdlSdDoyapESBsuHWZCDQ4bQiK@@W5kWX4B)):

```
72.0200303030303
[[2, 7], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3]]
```

Output for base 100 (I edited leading zeros in for clarity):

```
72.0200303030303
[[72], [02, 00], [30]]
```

Output for base 1000 (I edited leading zeros in for clarity):

```
72.0200303030303
[[072], [020], [030, 303]]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. In the solution you wrote, the values of the quotients and remainders of the divisions must be known in order to find the periodically repeating digits. Does that mean it's not possible to find them from the functions I wrote?

Comment: @noname_lonestar I guess it's possible to do it with your function, but it seems trickier and rather inefficient. Trickier to figure out the repetition, for example after seeing the digits 0200303030303, how do you know the next digits isn't a 5? And inefficient because for each digit, your function starts all over from scratch.

Comment: I see... Again, thank you for answering.

Comment: @noname_lonestar Or if your `f` function is all I get, then instead of "tricky" it's just *impossible*. Because even if you see some repetition, you can never be sure that there won't be an exception later. Of course eventually after enough digits you will have seen the complete repetition and there won't be exceptions later, but you can't know that. When I said "tricky", I had in mind that we could use the number's denominator as a limit, but if we don't have that, then there's no way to know when to stop.